# Field mappings remove field from arcpyTable to Table conversion

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, field-mapping

I want to export a table but would like to remove one of the fields before doing so using arcpy. I'm trying to use field mappings but am missing something:

```
fields = arcpy.ListFields("some_table")

for field in infields:
    print field.name

OBJECTID
APN_GROUND
APN_AIR
DATE_CREATE
DATE_UPDATE
EDITOR
COMMENT

fmap = arcpy.FieldMappings()
fmap.addTable("some_table")

fmap1 = fmap.removeFieldMap(fmap.findFieldMapIndex("Editor"))
arcpy.TableToTable_conversion("some_table","some_path","new_table","",fmap1)
```

The tool runs but the field is present in the output.

Comment: EDITOR != Editor

Comment: Where is "some_table" stored?

Comment: @FelixIP Yes. I did correct the capitalization. Same result, however.

Comment: @PolyGeo Some table is stored on an sde.

Comment: Does your code work when "some_table" is copied into a file geodatabase?  I think trying to reproduce ArcSDE issues in a File Geodatabase should always be an early step in troubleshooting them.

Comment: @PolyGeo Yes. I suspected that ArcSDE is befuddling things. Problem is that is where the data will always be coming from and this will eventually need to be a routine process.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function to hide fields (this can also be adapted to set field ratio etc. which is what I use it for):

```
import arcpy

fishnet = r'C:\Default.gdb\Fishnet_sample'
print([f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fishnet)])

def hide_fields(in_fc, fields_to_hide_list):
    fc_desc = arcpy.Describe(in_fc)
    fl = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_fc,fc_desc.baseName)
    src_field_info = arcpy.Describe(fl).fieldInfo
    for field in [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(in_fc)]:
        field_idx = src_field_info.findfieldbyname(field)
        if field in fields_to_hide_list:
            src_field_info.setVisible(field_idx,'HIDDEN')
        else:
            src_field_info.setVisible(field_idx,'VISIBLE')
    newfl = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_fc,in_fc+'_fl',field_info=src_field_info)
    return newfl

print([f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(hide_fields(in_fc=fishnet, fields_to_hide_list=['Urk','RUTA']))])

#arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(in_rows=hide_fields(in_fc=fishnet, fields_to_hide_list=['Urk','RUTA']),...
```

Print statements output:

```
['OBJECTID_12', 'Shape', 'OBJECTID_1', 'OBJECTID', 'RUTA', 'RUTANUM', 'Shape_Leng', 'Ruta_10km', 'RutaNum_10', 'Shape_Length', 'Shape_Area', 'Seq', 'Urk']
['OBJECTID_12', 'Shape', 'OBJECTID_1', 'OBJECTID', '', 'RUTANUM', 'Shape_Leng', 'Ruta_10km', 'RutaNum_10', 'Shape_Length', 'Shape_Area', 'Seq', '']
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why removing the field doesn't remove it from your output. I've found the following to work:

1. Creating a new field mappings object
2. Iterate through your original
   field mappings object adding each field to the new field mappings
   object. Skip adding the field you wish to not be in the new table.

Sample:

```
 infmaps = arcpy.FieldMappings()
 infmaps.addTable ("sometable")
 outfmaps = arcpy.FieldMappings ()
 for fld in infmaps.fieldMappings:
     if fld.outputField.name == "Editor": continue
     outfmaps.addFieldMap (fld)

 arcpy.TableToTable_conversion("some_table","some_path","new_table","",outfmaps)
```

Comment: I used your code but field is still there